# What does a yellow block on a line in WebStorm diff mean?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am trying to compare a branch locally.

WebStorm is showing the following...

[image]

When I pull the change in it says the files are now 'identical'.

But as soon as I commit the changes this difference appears again.

Does anyone know what this line means?

Answer (score 1):

The yellow block means whitespace. Your local copy of file contains additional whitespace which does not get commited (due to webstorm/git settings) but shows up on diff.

Answer (score 1):

May be its suggesting the whitespaces that are added to it. You pressed tab.